# Communication between hubs in signalr

Tags: c#, .net, signalr

I am new to signalr and I am creating an app that will have 3 kinds of clients (desktop c# app) (requestor, authorizator, administrator) when requestor creates a request, the authorizator and administrator must receive a notification, then, if the authorizator authorizes the request, the client and the administrator must receive a notification, basically that is the app flow.

I am planning to create 3 hubs, one for each kind of client, my questions are:

1. Is my approach ok for this kind of program?
2. How can I make the hubs talk to each other? Requestor to authorizator, authorizator to admin, requestor to admin

Comment: From your explantion, I think it would be better to have only one hub and to use groups for your 3 kinds of clients.
But if you want to go with 3 hubs, you can access the connections of a hub from outside (including from inside an other hub) : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#how-to-call-client-methods-and-manage-groups-from-outside-the-hub-class

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggesition, What do you mean with groups?

Comment: do you mean this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups, thanks it will help

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. You use Groups.Add(connexionId, name) to add clients to a group and Clients.Group(name) to select the clients belonging to a group